# How to Read and Format a Weblink .csv with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am learning Pandas, and trying to download a .csv from Morningstar with the Morningstar API.

There are some very well put together instructions on how to use the API have been provided here (although they are not Python specific)...  https://gist.github.com/hahnicity/45323026693cdde6a116

The sample weblink is that hahnicity uses in the example is:
http://globalquote.morningstar.com/globalcomponent/RealtimeHistoricalStockData.ashx?ticker=F&showVol=true&dtype=his&f=d&curry=USD&range=1900-1-1|2014-10-10&isD=true&isS=true&hasF=true&ProdCode=DIRECT

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd    
path='http://globalquote.morningstar.com/globalcomponent/RealtimeHistoricalStockData.ashx?ticker=F&showVol=true&dtype=his&f=d&curry=USD&range=1900-1-1|2014-10-10&isD=true&isS=true&hasF=true&ProdCode=DIRECT'

df=pd.read_csv(path)
```

However, what is returned is gibberish.  I am not sure how to make Pandas read this in the correct columnar form?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: When I try that URL it just hangs.  What do you get?

Comment: It hangs for about 20 seconds, and then downloads.

Comment: You can try:

path='http://globalquote.morningstar.com/globalcomponent/RealtimeHistoricalStockData.ashx?ticker=F&showVol=true&dtype=his&f=d&curry=USD&range=2013-1-1|2014-10-10&isD=true&isS=true&hasF=true&ProdCode=DIRECT'

Comment: That second link will download less historical data, so it should be a smaller file.

Comment: For me it downloads nothing.  It returns empty.

Comment: For me, it downloads a JSON file and not a CSV file

Comment: If I use ``pandas.read_json()`` I get ``ValueError: Expected object or value``

Comment: Its almost like the first half of the table is dividends, and then the second half of the table is end of day pricing.  But they are two different tabular formats.  Pandas must be getting confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I do not understand how to handle the JSON format that is stored as a .csv with Pandas... so I decided to use Quandl instead.  It solves my problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/<ticker_symbol>/data.csv?api_key=<api_key>')
```

This returns the end of day pricing for the ticker in question.

You can find there docs and register for an API key here:
(https://docs.quandl.com/docs/in-depth-usage).